# Blank text when using random package

Tags: python, random

I'm making a dice program and whenever I try to type "D4" (Since that's the only thing I have right now) I get the random numbers I coded in, then blank text.

I'm using:
Windows 10 Home
Python 3.6

This is my code:

```
from random import *
import os
import time
os.system('cls')

print("What dice would you like to roll?")

print("D4, D6, D10, D12, D20")

D4 = int(randint(1, 4))

D6 = int(randint(1, 6))

D10 = int(randint(1, 10))

D12 = int(randint(1, 12))

D20 = int(randint(1, 20))

age = int(D4)

diceI = input("Name: ")

if (diceI == D4):
    print("lol")

else:
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("4")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("2")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("3")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("4")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("1")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("3")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("2")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(random.randint(1,4))
```

I understand that this is very messy code so I'll try and explain why I have certain things the way they are.

First of all, this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cvmD.png

The reason why I have this is that if I just try to have the "if" statement in the general the code, nothing shows up. That's why I just have it show up with the actual code in the else statement.

Second of all, this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBoj0.png

I know this can be very easily simplified, but the thing I'm trying to do is to show random numbers before the actual result comes in, giving the effect that it is actually a die that you're rolling.

I really hope somebody sees this because I've been trying to fix it for around 5 days now.

Comment: `dice` is a string - so compare it to one - not to a integer. Also `randint´ produces a `int` - you do not need to convert it wiht `int(...)` to one.

Comment: ...What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

So if I did understand you right, this should do what you want:

```
import os
import time
from random import *

os.system('cls')

print("What dice would you like to roll?")

print("D4, D6, D10, D12, D20")

D4 = randint(1, 4) # No need for the int conversions. randint returns an int (as the name suggests)

D6 = randint(1, 6)

D10 = randint(1, 10)

D12 = randint(1, 12)

D20 = randint(1, 20)

age = D4

diceI = input("Name: ")

if diceI == "D4": # if the input you gave equals the string "D4"
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("4")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("2")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("3")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("4")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("1")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("3")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print("2")
    os.system('cls')
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(randint(1, 4)) # No need for the random.randint, since you used import *
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
if (diceI == "D4"):
```

Instead of

```
if (diceI == D4):
```

,because D4 is a string

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from comparing a string `diceI = input("Name: ")` with an integer stored inside a variable `D4 = int(randint(1, 4))`.

`diceI` is a string - so compare it to another string - not to a integer. Also `D4 = randint(1, 4)` is enough - randint already produces a integer, you do not need to convert it with `int(randint(1, 4))` into one.

You can get the dice to be rolled directly from the input and skip parts of your code like so:

```
import random 
import os
import time
os.system('cls')

print("What dice would you like to roll?")
print("D4, D6, D10, D12, D20")

dice = ""
# continue to ask for input until the input is one of the ones in the list
while dice not in ["D4", "D6", "D10", "D12", "D20"]:
    dice = input("Name: ")

diceNr = int(dice[1:])  # remove the D and convert the remaining number to integer

if (diceNr == 4):
    print("lol") 
else:
    # get a random number between 1 and diceNr 
    print(random.randint(1,diceNr ))
```

See [randint-Doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

> **random.randint(a, b)**
>   Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b